# imagecopy not working

Tags: php, gd

I was trying to form an image from multiple images that fall under a certain pattern. but in the end I only get a gray box and the date, despite the fact that the array of found images is not empty.

```
$name = $_GET['gn'];
$dest = 'images/sprites/';
$images = array();
$dir = getcwd() . '/images/thumb';

$dir_b = $dir.'/real-size';

$pattern = $dir_b.'/{'.$name.'}*.jpg';
$images = glob($pattern,GLOB_BRACE);
list($step_w,$step_h) = getimagesize($images[0]);

$fi = imagecreate($step_w*count($images), $step_h);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($fi, 200, 200, 200);
imagefill($fi, 0, 0, $bg);
imagealphablending($fi, false);
imagesavealpha($fi, true);
ksort($images);

foreach($images as $k => $i){
    $pi =  imagecreatefromjpeg($i);
    imagecopy($fi,$pi,$k*$step_w,0,0,$step_w,$step_h);  
    imagedestroy($pi);
}
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($fi, 0, 0, 255);

imagestring($fi, 5, 0, 0, date('H:i:s'), $textcolor);

imagepng($fi, $dest.$name.'.png');
imagedestroy($fi);
```

Where is the mistake and what can i do to fix it?

After some comments: I can safely say that the cycle passes all four times, each time a variable `$pi` is taking valid value

Comment: You do not check return values for error cases, e.g. what is `$r`? You should do some basic debugging first, otherwise users here need to guess like you, but they can not run your code.

Comment: Can you please make some var_dump($images), to check values of this array ?

Comment: @hakre, i thought that there is no reason to post here a fully secured foolproof code. I can say, that GET-parameter is valid and array is not null. `code`$r was used in debugging, forgot to delete.

Comment: I did not say you should post such an example, I just wanted to highlight that you can do better debugging with your code than anybody else here on site, so it would be useful to know where exactly your code fails. As your code does not show any efforts of error-checking I just was pointing to that because I'd say you should do that first.

Comment: @LaurentBrieu, var_dump says something like this: `array(4) { [0]=> string(85) "/mysite.com/images/thumb/real-size/avatar-image_1.jpg" [1]=> string(85) "/mysite.com/images/thumb/real-size/avatar-image_2.jpg" [2]=> string(85) "/mysite.com/images/thumb/real-size/avatar-image_3.jpg" [3]=> string(85) "/mysite.com/images/thumb/real-size/avatar-image_4.jpg" }`

Comment: @SuddenlyTork, you forgot one parameter in the imagecopy() function

Comment: @LaurentBrieu, thank you) I have already see it) such a stupid inattention to the end of workday)